# WP Super Cache versus W3 Total Cache

Tags: plugins, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, plugin-wp-supercache

I recently moved to a dedicated server and I've been having some problems with W3 Total Cache, server crashing, eating up a lot of RAM, back end interface becoming slow.. Everything appeared to work fine in shared hosting.. I am keen to try WP Super Cache.

I am using a lot of plugins and I hope the combination of WP Super Cache and WP Minify would do the job better than W3 Total Cache.

Any advice would be much appreciated as I have already spent a lot of research hours on the topic of caching but it seems that there is no clear answer as to the advantages and disadvantages of each option.

I am now on a 12GB RAM server and have to serve about 500 visitors per day..

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing something really wrong and **no caching solution is going to solve it**. Disable plug-ins on WordPress that you don't really need. If you use it once a month, you can enable it, use it, then disable it again. For example, I had bbPress installed but wasn't really using it and it took 11MB of memory.

500 visitors a day eating up 12GB of **memory** (are you sure that's memory and not bandwidth?) is a huge red flag. If everything worked fine in a shared hosting, and is now broken in your dedicated server, it's your server setup causing the problems. If you are on a managed server, I would have them fix the problem. If it's un-managed, you should get a managed server or go back to shared or start searching for help on fixing the problems/setup.

What shared host were you on? What dedicated server service are you using?

I'm assuming you mean 500 visits is 500 unique visitors, with more page views. 500 page views would be even lower demand site and any basic hosting site should be able to handle that.

500 visits is a low-demand site. I'm on a shared host and have served 2000 visits a day (with 15k page views) with less than 128MB of memory with minimal slowness.